# Consulta a MongoDB desde Python

Tags: python, mongodb

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta a MongoDB desde Python, me estoy adentrando en estas tecnologías apenas.

Tengo este código

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.crawler.users
res = db.find()

print( res )
```

Me arroja este mensaje:

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7f438d574cd0>
Process exited with code: 0
```

Yo esperaba un a respuesta así puesto que desde la consola de Mongo si la ejecuta:

```
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b3fd50706dd45b669417454"), "NAME" : "FOO", "LAST_NAME" : "BAR" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b3fdd2e613d0b159da70742"), "NAME" : "POO", "LAST_NAME" : "MAR" }
```

Agradezco su paciencia

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes poner el error completo?

Comment: Ya me explicaron que no es un error, es un objeto lo que está imprimiendo, pero como saco de ahí los document

Comment: `find` retorna un objeto `Cursor`, simplemente itera sobre el con un `for`, `for documento in res: ....` Mírate el ejemplo de la documentación : http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#querying-for-more-than-one-document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás imprimiendo el cursor. De acuerdo a la documentación, el método `find` retorna una instancia de [`pymongo.cursor.Cursor`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor). Para poder imprimir los documentos tienes que iterar el cursor:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.crawler.users
res = db.find()
for document in res:
    print(document)
```

Con eso deberías ver el contenido de cada documento de la colección. Se ve mejor si usas `pprint`:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint

client = MongoClient()
db = client.crawler.users
res = db.find()
for document in res:
    pprint(document)
```

Comment: Gracias sensei.